# How to draw a sprite in 3D

Tags: xna, c#, 3d, sprites

Until now, I've always used sprites to draw in 2D:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, rectangle, color);
```

(I suppose the texture is bound internally to 2 triangles and then scaled.)

Now, I'm porting my game to 3D and I have to draw several planes (walls, floor, roof,..). Do I need to manually bind a texture to a geometry (for example using `VertexPositionColorTexture` with `VertexBuffer` and `IndexBuffer`), or is there any simpler way to do that?

I'm looking for something like `spriteBatch.Draw` with the rectangle clip specified in 3D space:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, rectangleIn3D, color);
```

Comment: You need a manual implementation, Google 'billboards' - unfortunately SpriteBatch is built exclusively for 2D stuff.

Comment: While you *can* "kind of" use `SpriteBatch` in 3D ([starting point](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)), you probably *shouldn't* for what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a complement to Andrew's link, here's a more recent post Shawn wrote on this:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160125004311/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/01/12/spritebatch-billboards-in-a-3d-world.aspx)

But I don't recommend it either. That technique might be neat to create billboards and impostors, or placing text within a 3D world. But not to generate the floors and walls of an entire level.

If you're thinking about taking your 2D level data and procedurally generating a 3D level, I think you'd be better off writing an algorithm to generate all of the geometry from it (i.e. create and fill vertex index buffers, etc.).

Comment: Thanks.. that's what I was looking for. I know that isn't a good approach using 2d to simulate 3d, but I need it only for debug purposes. It saves me a lot of time.

Comment: Always good to have some shortcuts at hand for prototyping. :)

Answer (score 2):

Model and texturize your scenario with a 3d modeler like blender or 3ds max, export it to fbx, and load it as a 3d model in xna.